# How can I impute median values from Training data to test data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, training-data

I am trying to create a classification model and I am facing a problem while pre-processing the data frame. I have split the data into train and test, now I have replaced all the numerical columns in train using the median of their respective columns. Now I would like to replace the missing values in the test data by the median obtained from the training dataset. How can I achieve this in R? For example this is the code I am running to obtain median of all the columns in Train set. Please advise, I have about 86 columns in Both train and test, the code above just works on train set(if numeric it replaces median, if category it gets replaced by mode)

```
Mode <- function (x, na.rm) {
  xtab <- table(x)
  xmode <- names(which(xtab == max(xtab)))
  if (length(xmode) > 1) xmode <- ">1 mode"
  return(xmode)
}

for (var in 1:ncol(raw)) {
  if (class(raw[,var])=="integer") {
    raw[is.na(raw[,var]),var] <- median(raw[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
  } else if (class(raw[,var]) %in% c("character", "factor")) {
    raw[is.na(raw[,var]),var] <- Mode(raw[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Multiple packages include functions with this capability including [imputeMissings](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeMissings/) and [Hmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html).